# I want to execute this method in the plugin, what should I do

Tags: flutter

I am doing a function of external physical keyboard input, scan code gun to obtain data, execute this method, and then return to flutter app from the plugin

Now I have a problem, how to override this method in the plug-in, it is currently ineffective
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IBLh.png)

Comment: Please add an example that replicates your problem! https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0):

Flutter provides a way to communicate with the native platform code using `MethodChannel`.

From the flutter `MethodChannel` documentation ([here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=android-channel-java-tab)):

> Flutter uses a flexible system that allows you to call platform-specific APIs whether available in Kotlin or Java code on Android, or in Swift or Objective-C code on iOS.

> Note: If desired, method calls can also be sent in the reverse direction, with the platform acting as client to methods implemented in Dart. A concrete example of this is the [quick_actions][2] plugin.

**`MethodChannel` usage to invoke a function on native platform-code from flutter:**

We create a method channel object in Flutter, iOS, and Android with the same name. The Android and iOS objects will set a method call handler to receive calls from Flutter. The Flutter code can then call invokeMethod to call the handlers on the native objects

**Flutter:**

```
static final channelName = 'com.example.widget/keyEvent';
final methodChannel = MethodChannel(channelName);

await this.methodChannel.invokeMethod("dispatchKeyEvent");
```

**Android:**

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
  private static final String CHANNEL = "com.example.widget/keyEvent";

  @Override
  public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
  super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);
    new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL)
        .setMethodCallHandler(
          (call, result) -> {
            if (call.method.equals("dispatchKeyEvent")) {
              //TODO: Call the dispatch key event function here
              bool resultValue;

              if (data != null) {
                result.success(data);
              } else {
                result.error("UNAVAILABLE", "Result not available", null);
              }
            } else {
              result.notImplemented();
            }
          }
        );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, the function I want to achieve is to override the dispatchKeyEvent method in the plugin